# How to get value outside of second ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I have two API calls:

1. First API call gets a list of ISBNs.
2. Second API call gets information for each ISBNs from the ISBN list in step one.

The list in step 1 might contain 50 ISBNs but when checking for information for each ISBN in step2, if some information is missing, I do not want to display or count that ISBN.

My end goal is to count the total of ISBNs I have with the complete information but I cannot see to retrieve this because of Ajax is asynchronous.

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET",requestHTML,true)
request.send();

request.onload = parseXML;

function parseXML(){
    const xmlText = request.responseText;
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlText,"text/xml");

    var isbns = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("isbn");

    let counter = 0;
    for(isbn of isbns){
        let isbnString = isbn.textContent;
        let isbnURL = `https://openlibrary.org/api/books?jscmd=data&format=json&bibkeys=ISBN:${isbnString}`;
        $.ajax({            
            type: 'GET',
            url: isbnURL,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result){
                    ...
                    if(hasAllInfo){
                        $("#content_container").append(`<div class="book_container" id="${bookid}">`);
                        ...
                    }
                        counter ++;
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('ERROR');
            }
        })
    }
}
console.log("Total books found with all information:" + counter);
```

I would want the last line to display the total amount of ISBNs found which contains all the information but instead I get 0

Comment: You get 0 exactly because javascript is async. You should instead display that information after you have made all the calls in step 2.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, so you'll have to do everything upon success.

Comment: `counter++; if(counter === isbns.length){ /* last one */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty close, you just need to pull in the `console.log` into the step where you are incrementing the `counter`.

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET",requestHTML,true)
request.send();

request.onload = parseXML;

function parseXML(){
    const xmlText = request.responseText;
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlText,"text/xml");

    var isbns = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("isbn");

    let counter = 0;
    for(isbn of isbns){
        let isbnString = isbn.textContent;
        let isbnURL = `https://openlibrary.org/api/books?jscmd=data&format=json&bibkeys=ISBN:${isbnString}`;
        $.ajax({            
            type: 'GET',
            url: isbnURL,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result){
                    ...
                    if(hasAllInfo){
                        $("#content_container").append(`<div class="book_container" id="${bookid}">`);
                        ...
                    }
                    // changes here
                    if(++counter === isbns.length){
                      console.log("Total books found with all information:" + counter);
                    }
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('ERROR');
            }
        })
    }
}
```